# PowerShell Code Sigining: How to do use a self signed certificate with password protection?

Tags: powershell, security, code-signing

I am new to signing code with PowerShell. I successfully created a self-signed certificate and signed code using the following commands

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -dnsname "xyz" -Type CodeSigningCert
$codecert = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My\DF0E60B359BBADF625DCF4CA52C947F23713487F -CodeSigningCert)[0]
Set-AuthenticodeSignature .\test.ps1 $codecert
```

That works so far. However, I am a bit surprised that it offers no protection while using the certificate. If I log in with a different user with no administrative privileges I am able to sign code with this certificate as well.

I tried using the parameter `-PIN` like this:

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "meingeheimespasswort"
 New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -dnsname "xyz" -Type CodeSigningCert -PIN $pwd
$codecert = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My\DF0E60B359BBADF625DCF4CA52C947F23713487F -CodeSigningCert)[0]
Set-AuthenticodeSignature .\test.ps1 $codecert
```

The last command `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` then returns status "unknown error". It seems that there is no parameter like -password or -pin. Is that by the design and the reason why self-signed-certificates are said to be used only for testing?

For me, it appears to be a security risk if everybody could just use the existing certificate to sign code.

Thanks in advance for your help

Martin

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with Powershell. This has to do with where you store the certificate. Storing the cert in your user profile instead of the machine's store should prevent other users from using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bluuf is spot on.

You're storing the key in the local machine node of the Windows Certificate Repository, and then you're complaining another user on the local machine can access the certificate. This isn't really a Powershell problem. This is a you need to learn where to put your things problem.

> Local machine certificate store: This type of certificate store is
>   local to the computer and is global to all users on the computer.
>
> Current user certificate store: This type of certificate store is local
>   to a user account on the computer.

Reference: [Local Machine and Current User Certificate Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores)

Secure key and certificate storage is an industry unto itself. If you want to sign your code, you'll need to keep your keys and signing cert safe. The following is a good piece from Thawte:

https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/whitepaper/best-practices-for-code-signing-certificates.pdf

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. As I said..I am new to code signing therefore the confusion. I'll have a look at the whitepaper from Thawte.